# Selecting the second last digit in my table of MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

In my project, I want the detail of a user who selects the withdraw option or deposit option. How can I do that?

```
 SELECT *
    FROM `amount_flow`
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
    WHERE detail = 'withdraw' 

Edit    Delete  25  admin   03/03/14    12000   withdraw    3500
Edit    Delete  27  hi234   03/03/14    234     withdraw    3266
Edit    Delete  29  hifft   03/03/14    213     withdraw    3053 <-
Edit    Delete  57  hisat   03/03/14    130                 2800
```

Comment: could please name the column in the example?

Answer (score 1):

change

```
SELECT *
    FROM `amount_flow`
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
    WHERE detail = 'withdraw'
```

to

```
SELECT *
    FROM `amount_flow`
    WHERE detail = 'withdraw' or detail = 'deposit'
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: yeah brother i am appreciate